# Validate number if statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following statement where I just want to validate that user does not leave fields empty. My problem is at `productPrice`, if I uncomment those three lines, it will not work and get into `else` block even if the number I provide meets the criteria. If I leave it so only with `productPrice != ""` it will allow any string as value for `price` into the database. What is wrong here?

```
if (
    productTitle != "" &&
    productPrice != "" &&
    // Number.isInteger(productPrice) &&
    // productPrice > 0 &&
    // productPrice < 1000 &&
    productDescription != ""
) {
    let productData = {
        title: productTitle,
        price: productPrice,
        description: productDescription,
    };

    // .....
} else {
    console.log("All fields required");
}
```

Comment: how can a variable be a string and a number at the same time?

Comment: You can just remove `productPrice != "" &&` and use the rest of the commented conditions.

Comment: You can avoid unnecessary checks like string comparison and parsing if you use an <input type="number" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert **productPrice** from String, to Number(Integer), and then try compare with 0 & 1000.

```js
var pp = parseInt(productPrice) || 0;

if(
 ...
 !isNan(productPrice) &&
 pp > 0 &&
 pp < 1000 &&
 ...
){...
```

In the 1st line, we check if **productPrice** is **NaN**, so as to catch this exception.

Comment: I suggest you improve your answer by telling the user how to check for NaN. Don't want them to do a string comparison :)

Comment: For exmaple, `isNaN(productPrice)`?